# How to specify Library Provided at Runtime for Hibernate - Eclipse Dali JPA integration

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-tools, dali

I am trying to add Eclipse Dali JPA integration and to specify Hibernate as the JPA implementation.  I have gathered different instructions but am struggling with specifying the user library when configuring the project facet.  The page here (http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Developer_Studio/4.0/html/Hibernate_Tools_Reference_Guide/dali_integration.html) shows an option that says `Library Provided by Target Runtime` but I don't have this option.  I have `User Library` and `Disable Library Configuration`. I'd rather not download the hibernate jars and store them separately for eclipse configuration when I already have them specified in the project with maven.  And the disable option leaves the configuration in error.

Anyone have any tips for getting that option or another suggested Hibernate/JPA configuration within Eclipse?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are already doing library management with Maven and m2e, you should select Disable Library Configuration option. Yours is exactly the scenario that option was intended for. If you specify the errors you get when you follow this approach, someone may be able to help find the complete solution.

Alternatively, follow the User Library option and create a user library using the Hibernate jars you already have locally. There is no need to re-download them.

Comment: Oh ok.  I guess it's not an error but a warning that says I may need to do further configuration.  Be nice if there was a way to turn off that check but I guess thats ok as is.